# python Path from pathlib module doesn't add path separator

Tags: python, pathlib

I have the following issue using Path from the pathlib library:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

path_list = ["path","to","directory1","directory2"]
join_str = os.path.sep
my_path = join_str.join(path_list)
my_path = str(Path(my_path))
dir_exists = os.path.isdir(my_path)
Output:
my_path = "path/to/directory1/directory2"
dir_exists = False
```

I have tried with Path itself and manually giving it a path that I know exists:

```
(Pdb) test2 = str(Path("Users","userK","my_directory"))
(Pdb) os.path.isdir(test2)
False
(Pdb) test2
Users/userK/my_directory
```

I was wondering why Path doesn't simply add the backslash at the beginning? Is there a better way to build my path with the needed path separator from a list?
I didn't notice it before, because I use os.getcwd() and add to it to build my paths:

```
(Pdb) my_cwd = os.getcwd()
(Pdb) my_path = str(Path(my_cwd,"directory1"))
(Pdb) os.path.isdir(my_path)
True
```

However, I am not in the position code-wise to explicitly build the path I need, hence the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: can you do `Path(path).resolve()`, it will use the absolute path rather than relative path. In mac/linux, it'll be something like `/users/someone's mac/path/to/`

Comment: The only way that a joined path is going to be an absolute pathname is if you passed at least one absolute pathname to it - typically the first parameter, as an absolute path anywhere else will cause all previous parameters to be discarded as irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Path` cannot assume how the result will be used further, so it constructs the path object from the input data as is.

I will demonstrate with examples.

To begin with, prepare the directories in `/tmp`:

```bash
zyzop@localhost:~$ cd /tmp/
zyzop@localhost:/tmp$ pwd
/tmp
zyzop@localhost:/tmp$ mkdir -p path/to/directory1/directory2
zyzop@localhost:/tmp$ ls -ld path/to/directory1/directory2
drwxr-xr-x 2 zyzop zyzop 4096 Jul  8 03:28 path/to/directory1/directory2
zyzop@localhost:/tmp$ python3
```

Let's create a relative path from the list of its parts

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> path_list = ["path", "to", "directory1", "directory2"]
>>> my_path = Path(*path_list)
>>> my_path
PosixPath('path/to/directory1/directory2')
```

Since the relative path exists in the current directory, we can check its existence

```py
>>> my_path.exists()
True
>>> my_path.is_absolute()
False
>>> my_path.resolve()
PosixPath('/tmp/path/to/directory1/directory2')
```

There are two ways to create an absolute path. The first is to attach the path to the current directory to the beginning of the path

```py
>>> my_path1 = Path(Path().cwd(), *path_list)
>>> my_path1
PosixPath('/tmp/path/to/directory1/directory2')
>>> my_path1.is_absolute()
True
>>> my_path1.exists()
True
```

The second way is to explicitly specify the path from the root

```py
>>> path_list2 = ["/", "tmp", "path", "to", "directory1", "directory2"]
>>> my_path2 = Path(*path_list2)
>>> my_path2
PosixPath('/tmp/path/to/directory1/directory2')
>>> my_path2.exists()
True
>>> my_path2.is_absolute()
True
```

For example, let's see what happens to relative paths in another directory. Let's move to the home directory

```py
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir(Path.home())
>>> Path().cwd()
PosixPath('/home/zyzop')
```

Let's check the existence of paths

```py
>>> my_path
PosixPath('path/to/directory1/directory2')
>>> my_path.exists()
False
>>> my_path2
PosixPath('/tmp/path/to/directory1/directory2')
>>> my_path2.exists()
True
```

Now let's see how the absolute paths have changed. Since `my_path` is a relative path, it will always resolve relative to the current directory

```py
>>> my_path.resolve()
PosixPath('/home/zyzop/path/to/directory1/directory2')
```

`my_path 2` is an absolute path, so it will always be unchanged

```py
>>> my_path2.resolve()
PosixPath('/tmp/path/to/directory1/directory2')
```

More details can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Appreciate it! Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why `pathlib` does not add a slash at the beginning. If I had to guess, maybe sometimes it is not obvious what is the "root" of the file system (think windows with multiple disks) and also it is probably better this way.

Anyway, easy to add it yourself.

```
Path("/path/to/directory1/directory2")
Path("/Users/userK/my_directory")
Path("./directory1") # or Path.cwd() / "directory1"
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the root, you can use this syntax :

```py
from pathlib import Path
Path.cwd().root
```

Another approach could be :

```py
from pathlib import Path
Path("/") # Or Path("/").root
```

It works on UNIX, to test on Windows